# Apply bootstrap on div width change instead of window change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div which is expanding dynamically in my project. But I need to apply the bootstrap columns style for expanding div. I was applying based upon the window resize but not div size change.

Here My code was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").width($("div").width()+20);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
</head>
<body>
</br>
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:orange;width:200px;height:200px;">

    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis </p>
    </div>

</div>


<button>expand</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The button expands the div continuesly on each click.

Please help us on this to apply the bootstrap style to the dynamically expanded div.

Comment: remove width from <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:orange;height:200px;">

Answer (score 0):

1. you give you div inline style width in px.
2. parent div overflow:auto.
3. change width in column width in jquery

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($("div").width());
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div.col-sm-6").width($("div.col-sm-6").width()+20);
    });
});
</script>



<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:orange;height:200px;overflow:auto;">

    <div class="col-sm-6 " style="background-color:lavender;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 " style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis</p>
    </div>

</div>
<button>expand</button>
```